# Playing flash file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flash

I did some research and come up with this code.

```
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Stop()
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Movie = Application.StartupPath & "\RSAppt.swf"
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Play()
    playBtn.Enabled = False
```

I don't know why the video is not playing. My RSAppt.swf file is located at a resources(foldername) folder under my project. Is it the path? What is the right way to direct it to the specific path of my .swf file. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine.

Dim path As String = Application.Startuppath & "\yourfolder\yourfile.swf"

```
    AxShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, path)
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Play()
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Loop = False
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to have:

```
AxShockwaveFlash1.Show()
```