# Embed Flash in WPF application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, flash

Okay, so I had trouble to embed a Flash animation in a WPF application. I tried many things and only one actually worked for me.

I found a solution, so I'll post it below.

Comment: You need to post about one **specific** problem only then easier to fix it with **specific** correct answer.. Try something then ask here when stuck also adding snippet(s) of problem code. For example look at the _Related_ section on right-side : [**Playing flash file in vb.net**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467108/playing-flash-file-in-vb-net?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, I'm stuck on the way I can reproduce this application... I don't know what tools can help me to do "all" of things I want, as most of projects I found have limitations because of Microsoft licence or other things. I'm struggling since about 3 days of trying things... I know It's better to be specific, but actually I can't be more. I know how to embed flash in WinForms, the problem is to implement a _customizable_ ribbon. And it's the opposite in WPF, the ribbon is almost implemented, but can't embed Flash. By the way, I prefer to stay on WinForms.

Comment: I finally managed to add Flash in WPF, so I'll see if can continue on it for my project and I'll come back for further informations. I'll edit my first post with the solution to this *specific* problem :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I followed this tutorial, converting C# to VB: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/janiv/2009/09/20/embedding-and-communicating-with-the-macromedia-flash-player-in-wpf/

But at the end, I managed to end up with only 30 lines of code to do what I wanted at first...

Here's the code from WinForm User Control, **WFFlashPlayer.vb** :

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace FlashAxControls
    Partial Public Class WFFlashPlayer
        Inherits UserControl
        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            AxShockwaveFlash.Base = "#"
            AxShockwaveFlash.Movie = "#"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

In case, **WFFlashPlayer.Designer.vb** :

```
Namespace FlashAxControls
    Partial Class WFFlashPlayer
        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Required designer variable.
        ''' </summary>
        Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer = Nothing

        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Clean up any resources being used.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
            If disposing AndAlso (components IsNot Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Sub

#Region "Component Designer generated code"

        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        ''' the contents of this method with the code editor.
        ''' </summary>
        Private Sub InitializeComponent()
            Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(WFFlashPlayer))
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash = New AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash()
            CType(Me.AxShockwaveFlash, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
            Me.SuspendLayout()
            '
            'AxShockwaveFlash
            '
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.Anchor = CType(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
            Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.Enabled = True
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.Name = "AxShockwaveFlash"
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.OcxState = CType(resources.GetObject("AxShockwaveFlash.OcxState"), System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1125, 825)
            Me.AxShockwaveFlash.TabIndex = 0
            '
            'WFFlashPlayer
            '
            Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
            Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
            Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(239, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(239, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(242, Byte), Integer))
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.SimpleButton1)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.AxShockwaveFlash)
            Me.Name = "WFFlashPlayer"
            Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1125, 825)
            CType(Me.AxShockwaveFlash, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
            Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        End Sub

#End Region

        Private AxShockwaveFlash As AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Here's the WPF User Control, **FlashPlayer.xaml.vb** :

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Integration

Namespace FlashAxControls
    Partial Public Class FlashPlayer
        Inherits UserControl

        Private Sub FlashPlayer_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
            Dim host As New WindowsFormsHost()
            Dim player As New WFFlashPlayer()

            host.Child = player
            FlashPlayerGrid.Children.Add(host)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**FlashPlayer.xaml** :

```
<UserControl x:Class="FlashAxControls.FlashPlayer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="FlashPlayer_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="FlashPlayerGrid">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, here's my WPF application XAML code (a bit customized) :

```
<dxr:DXRibbonWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
        xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
        xmlns:dxr="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/ribbon"
        xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FlashAxControls.FlashAxControls;assembly=FlashAxControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="922" Width="1127" Background="#FFEFEFF2" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" BorderEffect="Default" IsAeroMode="False" DisplayShowModeSelector="False" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" ShowInTaskbar="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <controls:FlashPlayer Height="825" Width="1125"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</dxr:DXRibbonWindow>
```

I hope this can help someone.